# Combine excel files into one file python3.11

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I write a python script that combine multi excel files into one file
that contain Two columns in this format

```
Alpha number
  a    1
  b    2
  c    3
```

And I get the output file with six columns
How I can combine the two column instead of duplicate it?

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path =  "/Users/shoug/Desktop/ShouqTest"
os.chdir(path)

listOfFiles = os.listdir(path)

##listOfFiles=os.listdir(path)
##if '.DS_Store' in listOfFiles:
  ##listOfFiles.remove('.DS_Store')

df = pd.DataFrame()
print(df.shape) 

for entry in listOfFiles:
    print(entry)
    dfx = pd.read_excel(entry)
    dfx['Template'] = entry[:-17]
    ##df = df.append(dfx)
    df= pd.concat([df, dfx], axis= 1)
    print(df.shape)

df = df.drop_duplicates()
cols = [0,1]
df = df[df.columns[cols]]
df.to_excel(path + '_combined.xlsx', index = False)
```

[the combined file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hE4q.png)

Answer (score 0):

*Did you mean `axis=0`* ?

Also, you need to slightly adjust your code :

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

path =  "/Users/shoug/Desktop/ShouqTest"

df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.read_excel(fp).assign(Template=fp.name[:-17]) # or maybe fp.stem ?
        for fp in Path(path).glob("*.xlsx") # feel free to adjust the path'ern
    ], axis=0, # the default # ignore_index=True # uncomment if needed
    ).drop_duplicates()

df.to_excel(Path(path) / "ShouqTest_combined.xlsx", index=False)
```

This should generate a `_combined` spreadsheet with exactly three columns : `['Alpha', 'Number', 'Template']`.